# Tile quick project

Tags: c++

So I am new to C++. I'm learning the basics and I've been trying to make this program compile. Unfortunately, whenever I run it, the price of the tiles is, of course, very low and also the number of tiles does not come back in a reasonable way. Please help!

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


int main()
{
    double cost_tile, side_tile_in, width_room, lenght_room;
    cout << "How much is one tile? \n";
    cin >> cost_tile;

    cout << "What is the length of one side of a tile in inches? \n";
    cin >> side_tile_in;

    double side_tile_ft, tile_area_ft;
    side_tile_ft = side_tile_in * 12;
    tile_area_ft = side_tile_ft * side_tile_ft;

    cout << "What is the width of the room in feet? \n";
    cin >> width_room;
    cout << "What is the length of the room in feet? \n";
    cin >> lenght_room;

    double area_room, tiles;
    area_room = width_room * lenght_room;
    tiles = area_room/tile_area_ft;

    cout << "You will cover an area of " << area_room << " square feet, with " << tiles << "tiles \n";
    cout << "The cost for the tiles will be $" << cost_tile *  tiles;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: Since you're just starting C++ I'd *strongly* encourage you to learn about unit testing and building functions to encapsulate your code. Just having at it like this leads to a sprawling mess that's fundamentally a pain to test and verify. Some unit testing frameworks are [extremely light-weight](https://github.com/philsquared/Catch) but find one that fits your style and needs and use it thoroughly.

Comment: I just need help in general, the program is supposed to give how much area you will cover with tiles, how many tiles you will need, and the cost of the tiles. So I guess the question will be, am I doing right or not?

Comment: Thank You for the advice tadman!

Comment: You should include the input, the output and the expected output and explain how they differ. There is a fundamental difference between what a code does and what it is supposed to do, for now we only see what it does, so we cannot know what is wrong with it

Comment: and btw using a test framework for this problem is overkill imho, but of course you will need it once you write bigger applications

Comment: side_tile_ft = side_tile_in * 12;  Shouldn't this be divide rather than multiply? If you enter 12 for inches you want it to be 1 foot right?

Comment: For the input it would be whatever the dimensions and the price of the tiles that the user will want. Let's say the user inputs that the price for the tile is $1.69, the side of the tile of 13in, the width of the room as 120ft, the lenght of the room for 150ft. The expected output will be _You will cover an area of 18000 square feet with 12 tiles_ and then it will say _The price of the tiles will be of 20.28_

Comment: You would have faster response by using a Debugger.  The Debugger will allow you to execute each statement, one at a time, and watch the values of variables.  A very useful skill to learn and practice.  This program is a good candidate.

Comment: Instead I get stuff like _You will cover an area of 18000 square feet with 15337.3 tiles_ and then it will say _The price of the tiles will be of $25920_

Answer (score 2):

To convert inches to feet, divide by 12, not multiply by 12.

Comment: @CarlosGomez, Your post still shows *12.  How about fixing that, testing that new source, and adding the new output to the post?  That would help a lot.